# Deploying same contract with different owner using alchemy

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, alchemy

I am trying to deploy contract to polygon mumbai testnet. It works with the first wallet address, but when i use a different wallet address it doesn't work.
I am using the same alchemy rpc url

```
truffle migrate --reset --network first_owner //works
truffle migrate --reset --network different_owner //doesn't work
```

Second one is compiling fine, but no transaction

//UPDATE

Truffle Config file

```
networks: {
matic_test: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
      phrase: process.env.MEMONIC
    },
    providerOrUrl: process.env.ALCHEMY_API_POLYGON_TEST
  }),
  network_id: 80001,
  confirmations: 2,
  timeoutBlocks: 200,
  skipDryRun: true,
  gas: 6000000,
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
  from : "WORKING_ADDRESS"
},
matic_test_staging: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
      phrase: process.env.MEMONIC_STAGING
    },
    providerOrUrl: process.env.ALCHEMY_API_POLYGON_TEST
  }),
  network_id: 80001,
  confirmations: 2,
  timeoutBlocks: 200,
  skipDryRun: true,
  gas: 6000000,
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
  from : "DIFFERENT_ADDRESS"
},
}
```

Second one is only compiling but not deploying
Any idea?

Comment: --network should be the network specified on your `truffle-config.js` not the address of the owner

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i deployed my contract with one wallet address. I am trying to deploy the same contract under different wallet address. @AdamBoudjemaa. first_owner and different_owner is the configuration in truffle config file. I have updated the main question with the config file.

Comment: `truffle migrate --reset --network matic_test_staging` try this
do you have enough ETH / MATIC to deploy / run a transaction?

Comment: yes, tried it. didn't work. it shows compile complete but no new contract address. same call works with matic_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
Remove everything from the build folder and then build it